# Deploying WCF Services and 'The resource could not be found'

Tags: wcf

May be this is a newbie questions, I'm deploying a Ajax-enabled WCF Service on the production and it says 'the resource cannot be found' what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Oh it was due to my hoster using 3 domain names in IIS, so I had to use CustomHostFactory to work around that

http://zubairdotnet.blogspot.com/2008/08/error-collection-already-contains.html